# jQuery put with WebApi - Not even calling the Controller method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Sorry to ask a question about this so soon after asking another question but I'm now struggling with the PUT.

I have a jQuery method which collects the data and passes it to a PUT function in the valuescontroller. But the controller isn't even being called (As I have a break point on it and it isn't breaking)

Can I just check my jQuery is correct?

```
var data = {
            id: truckId,
            obj: {
                TruckId: truckId,
                Reg: reg,
                Description: desc,
                Condition: condition
            }
        };
        var json = JSON.stringify(data)

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Values',
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: json,
            success: function (results) {
                $.getJSON("api/Values", LoadTrucks);
                alert('Truck Updated !');
            }
        })
```

The controller looks like this:

```
public void Put(int id, TruckInfo obj)
    {
        WebApiTestEntities db = new WebApiTestEntities();

        var data = from item in db.TruckInfoes
                   where item.TruckId == id
                   select item;
        TruckInfo oldRecord = data.SingleOrDefault();
        oldRecord.Reg = obj.Reg;
        oldRecord.Description = obj.Description;
        oldRecord.Condition = obj.Condition;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Now it looks to me like that should at least be reaching the Controller. My guess is the parameters aren't being passed correctly and therefore it is looking for a different method but I can't see why or how to rectify that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Lex

EDIT: As requested, further information.

No Javascript errors on the error console.

The Console log displays the following:

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'localhost:62997/api/Values'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the request."}

And under MessageDetail for the JSON console I get this (Which supports my theory on incorrect parameters I think)

"No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the request"

The get however succeeds. (And the POST I got working earlier this morning.)

Comment: do you get any JS errors? could you also add a `console.log(json)` right before the `.ajax` call, and one in the `success` function ( like `console.log(results)` so you know that JS actually sent something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your code like below, then it will work fine:

```
var data = {
        TruckId: truckId,
        Reg: reg,
        Description: desc,
        Condition: condition
    };

var json = JSON.stringify(data)

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Values/' + truckId,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: json,
    success: function (results) {

    }
})
```

The best practice when using REST is:

1. User POST when creating new resource.
2. User PUT when updating existing resource and the Id of resource should be in the URL.
3. User DELETE when deleting existing resource and  the Id of resource should be in query string as well.

Comment: PUT requests should be directed at an identifiable resource the use of query parameters is not appropriate here... surely it should be a route of /api/Values/<ID>?

Answer (score 5):

You are doing a PUT request without specifying the ID of the object.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

> the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the
>   request

Change

```
url: '/api/Values',
type: 'PUT',
```

To

```
url: '/api/Values/' + truckId,
type: 'PUT',
```

The Routing engine will need to `id` to match to your method

```
public void Put(int id, TruckInfo obj)
```

At the moment you are attempting to put this in your model here:

```
id: truckId,
obj: {
   TruckId: truckId,
   //etc
```

But this will not work. Only one object is deserialisable from the body of the request.

Simply alter your message payload to this

```
var data = {
            TruckId: truckId,
            Reg: reg,
            Description: desc,
            Condition: condition
           }
```

And use the correct url structure e.g.:

```
PUT http://localhost:62997/api/Values/1
```

Comment: +1 for the reminding me about why the routing engine would not match the url pattern. I was assuming it is clever enough to pick up the id from the data object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or similar browser plugins to check the request that is made and the response that the server gives.

IIS could also be rejecting the `PUT` verb. I have run into the same problem. If this is the case, you should be able to fix it by changing or adding these handlers in your `web.config` file (section `<system.webServer>`):

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following configuration into your web.config file

```html
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```